# How can I make kernel trainable= False and recurrent_kernel trainable = False using standard Keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm, freeze, transfer

I understand that using Trainable = False, I can freeze all the weights of a specific layer. But I want to work on the components (kernel, recurrent_kernel and bias) of each layer as well. I want to freeze the kernel and recurrent_kernel of a specific layer to be Trainable = False and Trainable = True. How can I do it?

I tried the following code but got an error. Can anyone suggest to me how can I make kernel and recurrent_kernel Trainable = False using standard Keras?

```
#transfer model layer

lstm_layer = modelTL.layers[0]

#kernel non-trainable

lstm_layer.cell.kernel.trainable = False

#Error : lstm_layer.cell.kernel.trainable = False
```

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

After building the layer, you can separate the different variables and set them to `trainable` or not.

```
import tensorflow as tf

layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8)

layer.build(sequences_shape=(2, 4))

kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias, seed = layer.variables

kernel.trainable = False
recurrent_kernel.trainable = False
```

Comment: Hi, Nicolas Gervais, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried 
kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias = modelTL.layers[0].variables
1. With ‘kernel.trainable = False’, I got the error AttributeError: can't set attribute 'trainable'
2. 'kernel._trainable = False' works.
I printed the weights of layer[0] and got '#Kernel Trainable: False'
3. But when I print summary model, I see all are trainable params, whereas I was expecting some of the params from the layer[0] should be nontrainable Can you tell me why?
Total params: 3,180,548; Trainable params: 3,180,548; Non-trainable params: 0

Comment: before when I freeze the model layerwise, entire layer (modelTL.layers[0] = False), I got nontrainable params  
Total params: 2,064,388
Trainable params: 985,092
Non-trainable params: 1,079,296

Comment: Also, why with ‘kernel.trainable = False’, I got the AttributeError but 
with 'kernel._trainable = False', it  works?

Comment: Maybe a minimal and reproducible example would help. Along with your tensorflow version

Comment: Can you see this minimal and reproducible code?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bbhN7-ic-SjMOFPxvuf2I00A1xQTEwXN/view?usp=drive_link

Tensorflow version 2.11.0

Comment: No I am unable to can

Comment: I posted my code as an answer. Can you have a look? Why does the transfer model show the params are trainable? Also, why .trainable doesn't work but _.trainable works?